# can i post json object and parameter in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here is a question,
I'm using $.ajax to post to MVC controller.
my contentType & dataType is json.
i have no problem in posting a json object, but can i post a json object with some other parameters on the same post ? (like an id, or string) ?

ex:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data);
var id = 1;
$.ajax({
  url: 'some url',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    jsonObject: jsonObject, 
    id: id},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {

  },
  error: function (data, event) {

  },
});
```

**[EDIT] - Extra information** for question adding 'id' as property isn't helpful, since my object model on the server side (MVC) doesn't have a property 'id' for it. let's say my object model for 'data' is:

```
class Temp{
string name
string phone
}
```

now, when i "POST" the json to the controller in MVC i want to include the 'id' parameter on the POST.

so the controller looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SampleMethod (Temp temp, int id){
...
}
```

Comment: you already do by populating `data`-property - or am I missing sth?

Comment: Since you are stringifying your JSONObject, I don't see why you would be unable to do so. Is there a reason you think this is impossible?

Comment: the data property is missing the extra parameter on the object model, and i can't add it to the object model, so i need to figure a way to send a json and another parameter.

Comment: You can send json as data type html it is only for automatically parsing the response. you must then .parse() the response manually.

Comment: I am still not sure what the question is :/ could you please give some examples what the content of `data` should look like and where specifically you are struggeling?

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair, see below my EDIT on Axel Amthor answer

Comment: @eyalewin Additional Information to your Q goes into your Q and not in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to stringify the stuff, jQuery will do that for you:

```
// not necessary var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(data);
var id = 1;
$.ajax({
  "url": 'some url',
  "type": 'POST',
  "data": {
    "jsonObject": data, 
    "id": id
  },
  "dataType": 'json',
  "success": function (data) {

  },
  "error": function (data, event) {

  },
});
```

as well as content_type is not needed, `dataType` is setting this accordingly. On the server, you get (as Query Params):

```
...jsonObject=<stringified data>&id=1234...
```

[EDIT]

in order to only pass the data object, you might add `id` as property:

```
 var id = 1;
 data.myId = id;

 $.ajax({
    "url": 'some url',
    "type": 'POST',
    "data": data,
 ...
```